# asynchronous alert in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, alert

When our company's mapping website loads two things are supposed to happen:

- A dialogue box containing a disclaimer comes up
- Our map (GeoMoose) loads

In Firefox and IE, I am able to have the map load in the background while the disclaimer is displayed by using setTimeout to asynchronously call the alert() function. In chrome, the dialogue box displays and the map does not load. This costs .5 -1.5 seconds of precious load time while loading our rather large map. Is there a better way to asynchronously display an alert() message that will work in chrome?

Here is the pertinent code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertUser(){
setTimeout(function() {alert("here is our disclaimer");},1);
}
</script>


<body onload="main(); alertUser(); ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the map and when everything is loaded run `alert` from a callback. Should be relatively simple.

Keep in mind, you'll still be wasting ".5-1.5 seconds" of "precious" time the user could be spending using your map. You might want to put a `<div>` above the map with the disclaimer in it or something like that.